# Typescript - how to declare an attribute name started with @?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I'm trying to declare a type in TypeScript with an attribute named "@type" in order to correspond with some type from my Java API:

```
export interface Foo {
    id : string;
    name : string;
    @type: string;
}
```

However, I'm getting a compiler error in my VS Code.

Just to make sure it's not a JavaScript issue, I tried `let test = JSON.parse('{"@type" : "value"}')` in the browser console and it works fine.

So how can I declare such a type with an attribute name started with @?

Comment: Put it in quotes? EG: `{"@type": string}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript (and Typescript) have relatively liberal `member` naming rules; meaning that you can use uncommon characters and even space. But in order to do so, you need to encase them in `quote`s:

```
interface MyInterface {
    property1: string;
    "@property 2": string;
}

const myobj: MyInterface = {
    property1: "Value 1",
    "@property 2": "Value 2"
}
```

If you do use non-alphanumeric property names, you'd have to use the `index` syntax to access them:

```
console.log(myobj.property1); // Dot notation
console.log(myobj["@property 2"]); // Index notation
```

---

For more interesting and in-depth information, review [Mathias Bynens](https://mathiasbynens.be/)' blog entries:

- [Valid JavaScript variable names in ECMAScript 6](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers-es6)
- [Unquoted property names / object keys in JavaScript](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties)